# Loading F# modules not in the current directory

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2017, .net-core-2.0

I'm writing a simple F# console app with Visual Studio 2017 targeting `.NET Core 2.0`. I'm wondering if it's possible to `open` a module not present in the current directory.

For example :

`/root/foo.fs
/root/SubDirectory/bar.fs`

How can `bar.fs` open the `Foo` module or vice versa?

I already tried :

```ml
open Foo
open "../Foo"
open "C:/AbsolutePath/Foo"
```

With the last two ones, VS complained with :

> FS0010 : Unexpected string literal in open declaration. Expected identifier, 'global' or other token.

There seems to be no documentation about this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't `open` files, only modules and namespaces declared in files listed **before** the current file in your `.fsproj`. In VS2017 you should be able to create a project or add these files to and existing project, and reorder files.

Comment: It works differently in the context of an F# script, where you can use the `#load` directive to bring in other files based on their path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can only add or reorder files in VS2017 in the preview version I believe (so not yet on 15.5.6). But TheQuickBrownFox is correct, the file that has your module has to be in the `fsproj` file, and the order is important.

For VSCode, you can use the Command (or Project Explorer) in Ionide: Ctrl+Shift+P: `F#: Add Current File to Project` and also `F#: Move File Up/Down` (there's a right click meny on the F# Project Explorer as well.

In Visual Studio 2017 you can right-click the Project and choose `Edit .fsproj`. VS will reload the file automatically on save, so no need to unload a project like in VS2015. It will look something like this:

[image]

You can see that `MyModule.fs` is in the root of the project and the line with MyModule.fs needs to be above any other files that reference it. You can use Alt+Up/Down Arrow to move lines around.

[image]

Then you can just open this module and use it. For example `Add` is defined in this module.

[image]

I also added  the `#load` directive, this is only if you want to test it in FSI, and the compiler will ignore it.